# Python import error on local environment only

Tags: python, python-import

I have an application which is deployed on heroku and runs, with Python 2.7.6 . On the local machine, the same Python version, I get import error for the module where is located the launcher:

```
(VIRTUALENV)$ python pybossa/web.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pybossa/web.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pybossa
ImportError: No module named pybossa
```

The pybossa folder has __ init__.py with this content:

```
__version__ = "0.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Cornilescu said there was a problem in the local environment. This was present when I was installing requirements from inside the project (i.e. running `$ pip install -r requirements.txt` from inside pybossa project).

When running it from parent project the environment was ok (i.e. `$ pip install -r pybossa/requirements.txt` )

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a mismatch in the environment in the 2 execution cases.

You could set add the parent of the pybossa dir to your PYTHONPATH (just an example, but it's better to try to match the environments, other surprises can lurk in there otherwise):

```
$~/tmp> python pybossa/web.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pybossa/web.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pybossa
ImportError: No module named pybossa
$~/tmp> echo $PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH: Undefined variable.
$~/tmp> setenv PYTHONPATH '.'
$~/tmp> python pybossa/web.py
$~/tmp>
```